# How to use a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ to define an infinite interval in $\mathbb{N}$ (defn. of limits)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, metric-spaces

Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $f:\mathbf{N}\rightarrow E$ a mapping. Consider $\mathbb{N}$ as a subset of the extended real line and note that $\infty$ is a cluster point of $\mathbb{N}$. Suppose there exists $a\in E$ such that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty,n\in\mathbb{N}}f_n=a.$$
By definition, this means that
$$(\forall V')(V'\in\mathcal{U}_E(a)\Rightarrow(\exists V)(V\in\mathcal{U}_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}(\infty)\land f(V\cap\mathbb{N})\subset V')).$$
I want to show that this is equivalent to
$$(\forall V')(V'\in\mathcal{U}_E(a)\Rightarrow(\exists m)(m\in\mathbb{N}\land(\forall n\geq m)(f_n\in V'))).$$

Let $V'\in\mathcal{U}_E(a)$. There exists $V\in\mathcal{U}_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}(\infty)$ such that $f(V\cap\mathbb{N})\subset V'$. Obviously $V\cap\mathbb{N}\ne\emptyset$. How can I use $V\cap\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{N}$ to find the $m$ for which $(\forall n\geq m)(f_n\in V')$?

**Edit:** $\mathcal{U}_A(x)$ denotes the set of neighborhoods of $x$ in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is immediate from the definition of the topology on $\overline{\Bbb R}$: $\{(r,\infty]:r\in\Bbb R\}$ is a local base at the point $\infty$, so there is an $r\in\Bbb R$ such that $(r,\infty]\subseteq V$. Now let $m=\min\big(\Bbb N\cap(r,\infty]\big)$.

Comment: Thank you. I am using using the metric on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ defined by the bijection of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ onto $[-1,1]$. So I need to prove that $((r,\infty])_{r\in\mathbb{R}}$ is a fundamental system of neighbourhood of $\infty$, before I can use your method. Let $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in(r,\infty]$. I have to find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}(x;\varepsilon)\subset(r,\infty)$. How should I find such an $\varepsilon$? This will show that $(r,\infty]$ is a neighbourhood of $\infty$ for each $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @guam: It’s easier than that. If $f$ is the particular bijection that you’re using, let $s=f^{-1}(r)$. Then $f\big[(s,1]\big]=B_{\overline{\Bbb R}}(\infty,1-s)$.

Comment: I am sorry; I am not sure I understand. What is the use of $B_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}(\infty, 1-s)$? Also if $r<-1$ or $1<r$, then $f^{-1}(r)$ isn't defined, right? I am using $f:x\mapsto x/1+|x|$ naturally extended to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: @guam: I took $f$ from $(-1,1)$ to $\Bbb R$, so $f^{-1}(r)$ is defined for all real $r$. $B_{\overline{\Bbb R}}(\infty,1-s)$ is the open $(1-s)$-ball at $\infty$, so it’s a basic open nbhd with respect to the metric $d(x,y)=|f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(y)|$. If you used a bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $(-1,1)$ instead, my $f$ is your $f^{-1}$ and vice versa.

Comment: I see. The idea is to show that $(r,\infty]=B_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}(\infty,1-s)$, right? Thank you!

Comment: @guam: Yes, exactly.